# Startup script doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04

I've recently started using Google's Compute engine for some of my projects the problem is my startup script doesn't seem to work, For some reason my script just doesn't work, the VM has the startup-script metadata and it works fine when I run it manually with:

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
```

Here is what I am trying to run on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm -f Eve.jar
sudo rm -f GameServerStatus.jar
wget <URL>/Eve.jar
wget <URL>/GameServerStatus.jar
sudo chmod 7777 Eve.jar
sudo chmod 7777 GameServerStatus.jar
screen -dmS Eve sh Eve.sh
screen -dmS PWISS sh GameServerStatus.sh
```

There are no errors in the log either, it just seems to stop at the chmod or screen commands, Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. I think the problem is with "screen"

Comment: I have the same issue, too. When I run the script above `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`, it works perfectly, but if I reset my VM instance the startup script doesn't work.

Comment: Finally, I got the answer like below

Answer (score 15):

To add to kangbu's answer:

Checking the logs in container-optimized OS by

```
sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service
```

showed that the script could not find the user. After a long time of debugging I finally added a delay before the sudo and now it works. Seems the user is not registered when the script runs.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

sleep 10  # wait...
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd > /home/user/users.txt  # make sure the user exists
cd /home/user/project  # cd does not work after sudo, do it before
sudo -u user bash -c '\
source /home/user/.bashrc && \
<your-task> && \
date > /home/user/startup.log'
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem @Brina mentioned. I set up metadata key `startup-script` and value like:

```
touch a
ls -al > test.txt
```

When I ran the script above `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`, it worked perfectly, However if I reset my VM instance the startup script didn't work. So, I checked startup script logs

```
...
Jul  3 04:30:37 kbot-6 ntpd[1514]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fe80::4001:aff:fe8c:7 UDP 123
Jul  3 04:30:37 kbot-6 ntpd[1514]: peers refreshed
Jul  3 04:30:37 kbot-6 ntpd[1514]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Jul  3 04:30:38 kbot-6 startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
Jul  3 04:30:38 kbot-6 startup-script: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
Jul  3 04:30:38 kbot-6 startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 0.
Jul  3 04:30:38 kbot-6 startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

Yes. they found startup-script and ran it. I guessed it had executed as an another user. I changed my script like this:

```
pwd > /tmp/pwd.txt
whoami > /tmp/whoami.txt
```

The result is:

```
myuserid@kbot-6:/tmp$ cat pwd.txt whoami.txt
/
root
```

Yes. It was executed at the `/` diectory as `root` user. Finally, I changed my script to `sudo -u myuserid bash -c ...` which run it by specified userid.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the VM instances page.
2. Click on the instance for which you want to add a startup script.
3. Click the Edit button at the top of the page.
4. Under Custom metadata, click Add item.
5. Add your startup script using one of the following keys:

startup-script: Supply the startup script contents directly with this key.
startup-script-URL: Supply a Google Cloud Storage URL to the start script file with this key.

It is working. The documentation for the new instance and existing instance as shown in [GCE Start Up Script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)

Startup script output is written to the following log files:

1. CentOS and RHEL: /var/log/messages
2. Debian: /var/log/daemon.log
3. Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 16.10: /var/log/syslog

On Ubuntu 12.04, SLES 11 and 12, and all images older than v20160606:

```
sudo /usr/share/google/run-startup-scripts
```

Comment: I have already added the startup script wen creating the instance -
 As I said the script works when i run it manually with `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup` but not when the VM restarts.
http://prntscr.com/f9zvhg

Comment: ok, great! did you check the logs in the instance?  are there any errors?

Comment: Does not seem to be any errors from what I can tell. - https://pastebin.com/n3pTegUn

Comment: As per the screen shot the script is working without errors. Can you edit the question with the exact issue?

Comment: Edited the question although I'm not sure how else I can explain it since there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

think that you do not need `sudo`, as well as the `chmod 7777` should be `777`

also a `cd` (or at least a `pwd`) at the beginning might be useful.

... log to text file, in order to know where the script may fail.