# Run scripts on start up on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) does not work for some scripts?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I have a Linux machine on GCP and followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/1089494) to add a startup script. When my file is the following it perfectly works and creates a log file when the machine starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

with open('./my_log.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello Saeed\n')
    f.close()
```

However, when I change it to any other files like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from package import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

I do not see the run file on my python process when the machine starts. I use `ps -fA | grep python` to see my python processes.

Can you please help me to figure this out?

Edit:

I import some packages it does not work.

Comment: did you try "@reboot cd /path/to/directory && /usr/bin/python3 your_script_ name.py"?

Comment: This [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) might be useful. Can you check and confirm? Also refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084713/startup-script-doesnt-seem-to-work/53678027) which is similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check out the "official" way to install and run a startup script on a GCE VM: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts. Using a cron job might work, but it's sort of a "low-level" solution given that GCP provides more managed and theoretically more straightforward ways to provide a script that should be executed every time your VM starts up.

As per your script, it might be a couple of things: either it finishes executing before you have a chance to run `ps -fA | grep python`, or it may be failing for some other reasons, probably missing dependencies. You can try the following test: run your script as `root` with `sudo ./your_script.py`. You should be able to see some errors and then you can start troubleshooting those to find a solution to your problem. The reason you need to run the script as `root` is that startup scripts are run as root, and thus such a test will represent what will happen at startup time more closely.

If you see missing dependencies problems you should be able to solve them by installing the python dependencies (like `numpy`) at the system level using a command like `sudo pip install numpy`. If you don't want your script to run as `root` you can also add the username that you want your script to be run as after the command in the crontab:

```
@reboot /path/to/script username
```

Hope this gets you on the right path :)

Comment: I have done all the above but still does not work!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Did you get any errors from trying to run your app as `sudo`? If so, can you share them with us?

Comment: B: I installed every packages using `sudo`. The python script is run and works very well until I call my function. For assignment statements or `loop` and `while` it works but when I call a function that is in my scripts it is not run. However, this script is run flawlessly in terminal and calls my function and execute it.